# VS 2015 Addin: Name and type of object at the current text point

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-addins

I am trying to determine the name and the type (wheter the object is a method, property, etc.) of the element in which the caret is currently placed for a Visual Studio Plugin. I already tried to use CodeElements, but I'm just able to receive the elements declared in the current document and found no way to get the desired information.

Example:

```
Console.Wr|iteLine(); // Caret is placed after the 'r'
```

In above's short example, I want to receive "WriteLine" as the current object's name and I'd like to know that it is a method. Is there a simple way to do this? Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use Roslyn code analysis. See for example [Create a typed variable from the current method invocation](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#CreateTypedVariable). It finds Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMethodSymbol from the current text point.

Comment: Thank you a lot, your solution gave me exactly what I was searching for!